# Adding custom PHP form to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm still rather new to PHP, I've coded a form, but its purpose is going to be adding it onto a page in Wordpress, the only thing is, I'm not sure how I would go about doing so (in the quickest and easiest way possible)

Here's the current code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['person1'])) $person1 = $_POST['person1'];
if (isset($_POST['person2'])) $person2 = $_POST['person2'];
$multivar = 4;
$answer = ($person1 + $person2) * $multivar;

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='index.php'>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>How much can you borrow?</strong></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Person 1 income:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='person1' value="$person1"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow2"><td>Person 2 income</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='person2' value="$person2"/></td></tr>
<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>
_END;
?>

<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>You can borrow up to:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($answer)?>"></td></i>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I was thinking, if I split the PHP code off into a separate .php file, then use the HTML form inside the Wordpress page, and change the form action to the name of the file, then it would work, however for some reason when I attempted it that way, it never worked.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

What the quickest, and perhaps conceptually easiest way to get, would be to create a "page template" in your theme. That lets you run php like a normal php script.

Look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

What I'd do is copy your page.php template to something custom, and take it from there.

A more advanced way to do this, would create your logic code in a plugin, and use a shortcode to embed the form inside a post or page, for example.

Comment: The second method you proposed seems like it would be far too complex for me, considering I currently have a limitations with my ability to code PHP.

However, the first option seems more suited to me, I'll check it out, thanks!